# How to remove Stellar local node setup completely?

Tags: stellar-core, testnet, nodes

I am having some issues accessing the local node setup.

I installed with [this link](https://github.com/stellar/packages#installing-individual-packages) and tried to fix it but now I want to remove the complete setup and reinstall it.